# iPhone app crashes after loading it from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that crashes when i try to load it after it has been put in the background.
The first few times i put it in the background and relaunch it by multi-tasking (i.e double clicking the home button and getting the app in foreground) it works fine.

But if i keep putting it in background and keep re launching it after a few time it crashes and gives me the below error:

```
* __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76d6e90 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.199 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76d4880 of class NSException autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.200 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76b3c90 of class _NSCallStackArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.200 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76cbc30 of class _NSCallStackArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.201 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76c6db0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.202 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x78e5000 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.203 Snake[15192:ee27]  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x76c6a90 of class NSConcreteMutableData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2010-09-15 20:38:39.207 Snake[15192:ee27] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No background task exists with identifier 8'
```

Everytime the app crashes there is a different identifier number.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you overriding `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:`? If so, post the code.

Comment: Are you calling the endBackgroundTask: method on UIApplication?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the crash report for some assistance on where the problem is happening.